# QTreeWidgetItem editing finished slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

For a while now I am trying to figure out how to trigger a signal when an item in a QTreeWidget is edited. I tried to use the slots like currentItemChanged, ItemEntered and others from the QTreeWidget but they do not trigger. I would aprichiate all help in this matter!

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: [`QTreeWidget::itemChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#itemChanged): `This signal is emitted when the contents of the column in the specified item changes.`

Comment: Ah yes I have just noticed it as well. Thank you.